# Having trouble displaying values retrieved from multiple APIs to Ag-Grid rows (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm having trouble with this issue for the past couple of days and I've tried somethings but they haven't been working.

I'm trying to display some stock information onto the table. It works fine for one stock however when I try to get multiple stock information and combine it, I get blank values.

Please have a look at the code

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          try {
            let data = []
            data.push(await getAppleData())
            data.push(await getIBMData())
            console.log(data)
            setRowData(await data);
            setLoading(false);
          } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })();
      }, []);
```

Here is what one of the get[name]Data() functions look like:

```
async function getAppleData() {
        const url = `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/AAPL?apikey=APIKEY`;
        let res = await fetch(url);
        let data1 = await res.json();
      
        return data1;
      }
```

In the columns section I have tried these specifications but they aren't working

```
const columns = [
        { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol", 
        valueGetter: function (params) {
          return params.data.symbol;
        },},
        { headerName: "Price", field: "price" },
        { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry" }

      ];
```

The output I get is this:

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXJ6A.png)

Also this is the console.log of the rowData

[console.log(rowData)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRkFF.png)

Please can someone help me figure out how to reference the values from the array of objects?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing `setRowData(await data);`? Data is not a Promise so awaiting it makes no sense, try `setRowData(data);`

Comment: Looks like you are passing an array of arrays to `setRowData`, but I think it expects an array of objects. Try returning `data1[0]` from `getAppleData` and probably the same from `getIBMData`. And @AnonymousPanda is right, there's no reason to have `await data` in `setRowData`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right it doesn't make sense, I'm not sure why I added that, I changed it to just data but it's still showing the same result as in the Table Output screenshot

Comment: @tromgy Thank you so much, this has made it work! I changed it to data1[0] for both the get functions and I removed the await and I also removed the valueGetter function and it looks perfect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will append the entire response to the `data` array, and looks like the response is an array containing a single object, so `data` contains two arrays instead of two objects.

To append the objects instead of the arrays, you can use [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      let data = [].concat(await getAppleData(), await getIBMData());
      console.log(data);
      setRowData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

You can also use the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      let data = [...(await getAppleData()), ...(await getIBMData())];
      console.log(data);
      setRowData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Also, awaiting `data` makes no sense, so simply do `setRowData(data)`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the assistance! I tried using concat but now the data and rowdata variables are empty in the console.log

Comment: So, `console.log(data)` prints an empty array with `concat` and with `push` it printed an array with two items (as in the screenshot)?

Comment: Yes, I ended up making it work from @tromgy's advice above, I still used push but returned the data1 as data1[0] instead.

Comment: I have just tried it now, on the console.log it returns just a [] which is empty of any values and on the table it states 'No Rows To Show' instead of blank values like in the Output Table screenshot.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check now, it should work. I made a silly mistake `concat` returns a new array and does *not* mutate the original array like `push`.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, this works perfectly as well now, I used the Array.Prototype.Concat method described above and it works and there's no need to change data1 to data1[0] using this method. Thanks a lot!